# What tools to choose for developing a simple GUI application?

Tags: user-interface

I'd like to implement a very simple application, which would:

- Get a number from bar code reader
- Fetch some data from MySQL based on the number
- Based on the data, draw max 10 selection boxes on the screen of a touchscreen display
- User points at the boxes she wants to select
- Application updates database according to user's selection

The selection screen should be aesthetically pleasing and "fill" the whole display.

Application can implemented for either Windows or Linux, but the development environment and other tools should be either free or low cost.

The software will not be made available for download, but it will only be installed in a couple of computers.

My experience is mostly from server side applications, so I welcome suggestions for the technology which would enable fast development of such an application.

Comment: The real question is support for the barcode reader. Does it appear to be a normal file? Fine, any platform will work. Or do you need a special library to access it?

Comment: Generally barcode scanners act as basic keyboards.

Comment: I have also the impression that the barcode readers just input the text like a keyboard

Comment: The world has moved on since I worked with barcode readers :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Visual C# Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) is **free** and really easy with WinForms and its databinding. You can add this [MySQL ADO.NET driver](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely have to download this and give it a try. It looks promising.

Answer (score 4):

Two interesting development suites for simple (and possibly advanced) crossplatform GUI applications are [RealStudio](http://www.realsoftware.com/realstudio/) and [LiveCode](http://www.runrev.com/products/livecode/livecode-platform-overview/) (previously called Runtime Revolution).

Answer (score 1):

You have [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org), QT and GTK+, which have bindings to a lot of languages, including:

- Python: [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/), [PyQT](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQ) and [PySide](http://www.pyside.org), [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/)
- C
- Perl: [wxPerl](http://wxperl.sourceforge.net/), [PerlQT](http://perlqt.sourceforge.net), [GTK2-Perl](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net)
- Lua: [wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net), [LQT](http://code.google.com/p/lqt), [LuaGnome](http://lua-gtk.luaforge.net)
- Countless others [languages](http://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.html)

All of them are simple to use, some of them more than others, but for simple CRUD applications all of them will be similar.

I personally like wxPython for its great built in widgets, but you might want to try out the QT bindings, as they are considered to be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

[GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) is nice, cross-platform, easy to use etc. There is Glade for designing the UI... and it is free.

Comment: All GTK applications I know of are are "ugly". Is it easy to add eye candy?

Answer (score 0):

You can create such an application very quickly in either .net or Java environments. Because of the Windows or Linux point that you made I would favour Java, but if you are more experienced with .net then you may be able to use mono on linux.

If you choose Java then either Eclipse or Netbeans are very good IDEs with Visual Editors to assist with creating GUI apps.

Comment: Examples of GUIs made with Eclipse Visual Editor don't look too fancy.

Comment: @tputkonen That's right. The examples are not great. That is not a limitation of the environment though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question cannot easily be answered because it lacks a lot of important information. E.g. what programming language? Of what use is a framework only available for a set of programming languages that you all don't know and don't want to learn just for this project? What platform(s)? Of what use is a framework available for certain platforms, but none of them is your target platform? Or of what use is a framework available for some of your target platforms but not for others?

You should at least give a selection of programming languages you are willing to use and one or multiple platforms on that your final application is supposed to run .

Comment: Preferred programming languages could be for example PHP, Python, Java, C#, Basic. It doesn't matter though if we have to learn another language, that's why I left the language out. (There might also be tools which could be used for implementing this without too much programming.)

List of the environments was included in the question: Linux or Windows XP/Vista.

Comment: @tputkonen: Your question only said either Windows or Linux. Does that mean you can pick between either one (as that is how I read it) or does that mean it must run on *both*? And Linux is a wide field. Do you have total control over the Linux distribution or do you have to work with what other distributions offer by default? Also Windows is a wide field. Between Windows 95 and Windows 7.x exist a huge range of different Windows versions that might be or might not be supported by different frameworks, that's why I asked ;-)

Comment: Ok. We are planning to run the software on a couple of kiosks in our own premises. So we can set up the environment as required. Either Linux or Windows, or both is fine. In Windows I expect XP to be supported.